# Is it possible to construct an empty Message from a Descriptor?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

That is, given a [`Descriptor`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor#Descriptor), is it possible to construct the corresponding empty `Message` equivalent to calling `default_instance()` on the class? I don't need the actual subtype, I need only the abstract `Message`.

In particular I'm interested in enumerating instances of all `Message`s in a protobuf file, but using the API I was only able to enumerate all their `Descriptor`s.

Answer (score 1):

The interface you're looking for is [`MessageFactory`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message?hl=en#MessageFactory). Given a `Descriptor`, it can give you a default instance of that type. (You can call `message->New()` on the default instance to get a new mutable instance.)

There are two main kinds of `MessageFactory`. If the types you are interested in are compiled into your program binary, then you want to use `MessageFactory::generated_factory()`, which returns a `MessageFactory` that instantiates compiled-in types.

If the types are not compiled in, then you'll want to create a [`DynamicMessageFactory`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.dynamic_message), which is able to construct a `Message` behaving like any arbitrary type -- but note that due to the dynamic nature, using this instance will be slower than a compiled-in type (much like interpreted languages are slower than compiled ones).